# How to improve this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I would appreciate any suggestions on improving this linq query. I am querying a list of invoices, with the objective of finding the customer with the highest invoice total for each month. I then want to display the year, month, customer and invoice total.

The invoice:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

The data context to create a list of invoices:

```
 public class DataContext
    {                
        private List<Invoice> _invoices;
        private List<string> _customers;

        public List<Invoice> Invoices
        {
            get
            {
                if (_invoices == null)
                {
                    _customers = new List<string>(){ "Jim", "John", "Jeff", "Joe", "Jack"};
                    _invoices = new List<Invoice>();
                    Random random = new Random();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    {
                        _invoices.Add(new Invoice() {
                            Customer = _customers[random.Next(0, 5)], 
                            Date = new DateTime(random.Next(2010, 2015), random.Next(1, 13), random.Next(1, 20)),
                            Amount = random.Next(1,1000)
                        });                     
                    }
                }
                return _invoices;
            }
        }
    }
```

The query:

```
 DataContext context = new DataContext();  

 var invoiceTotalsByMonth = from invoice in context.Invoices
                            group invoice by invoice.Date.Year into yearGroup
                            orderby yearGroup.Key
                            select new
                            {
                                 Year = yearGroup.Key,
                                 Months = from year in yearGroup
                                          group year by year.Date.Month into monthGroup
                                          orderby monthGroup.Key
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              Month = monthGroup.Key,
                                              CustomerTotals = from month in monthGroup
                                                               group month by month.Customer into customerGroup                                                                       
                                                               select new
                                                               {
                                                                   Customer = customerGroup.Key,
                                                                   Total = customerGroup.Sum(i=>i.Amount)
                                                               }
                                                  }
                                     };

            foreach (var year in invoiceTotalsByMonth)
            {
                Response.Write(year.Year + "<br/>");

                foreach (var month in year.Months)
                {
                    var maxCustomer = month.CustomerTotals.First(i => i.Total == month.CustomerTotals.Max(j => j.Total));

                    Response.Write(month.Month + ": " + maxCustomer.Customer + " - " + maxCustomer.Total.ToString("c") + "<br/>");
                }
            }
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: This maybe better suited for [codereview.se]

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with this but I will look into it. Is there a way to transfer this post to the Code Review?

Comment: No worries! Click "flag" near the bottom of your question, then select "other" and say that your question maybe better suited for Code Review. The moderators will take a look ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that:

```
DataContext context = new DataContext();

var invoiceTotalsByMonthQuery = from i in context.Invoices
                                group i by new { i.Date.Year, i.Date.Month } into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    Year = g.Key.Year,
                                    Month = g.Key.Month,
                                    Customer = g.GroupBy(x => x.Customer)
                                                .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Total = x.Sum(y => y.Amount)})
                                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Total)
                                                .First()
                                };

var invoiceTotalsByMonth = invoiceTotalsByMonthQuery.OrderBy(x => x.Year)
                                                    .ThenBy(x => x.Month);

foreach(var item in invoiceTotalsByMonth)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1} - {2} ({3})", item.Month, item.Year, item.Customer.Name, item.Customer.Total);
}
```

One advice: it's **probably** better to use `OrderBy` + `First` instead of `First` + `Max` to find item with the max property value.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this solution with grouping by the anonymous type to eliminate the nested groups. But, why is OrderBy + First better than First + Max?

Comment: Good question. It's definitely more readable. Does it perform better? I'm not sure, but I'm gonna test that. The best way to go for that kind of problems is to use `MaxBy` (moreLINQ), but it's not part of standard LINQ.

Comment: Performance appears to be about equal, within a few ms. But I prefer the readability and conciseness of yours as opposed to the messy nested grouping I was working with. Thanks!